# VueJS getting "undefined" data from ipcRenderer (ElectronJS)

Tags: vue.js, electron

When trying to get a message from `ipcMain` to `ipcRenderer` (without node integration and with `contextIsolation`), it's received but as `undefined`. Not only that, but if I were to reload the `VueComponent` (regardless of what change I make to it), the number of responses gets doubled.

For example, the first time I start my application, I get 1x `undefined` at a time every time I click the button. If I reload the component, I start getting 2x `undefined` every time I click the button. I reload again and get 4x `undefined` every time I click the button... and it keeps doubling. If I restart the application, it goes back to 1x.

[image: undefined]

**SETUP**

ElectronJS + VueJS + VuetifyJS has been set up as described [here](https://itnext.io/electron-application-with-vue-js-and-vuetify-f2a1f9c749b8?gi=38126af37068).

**preload.js** as per the [official documentation](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration).

```
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
  send: (channel, data) => {
    // whitelist channels
    let validChannels = ['toMain']
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
    }
  },
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    let validChannels = ['fromMain']
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
    }
  }
})
```

**background.js** (main process) as per the [official documentation](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#preload-files) for the `preload.js` file. The omitted code via `...` is the default project code generated upon creation.

```
...

const path = require('path')
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')

async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({

    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
    icon: 'src/assets/icon.png',
  })

  ipcMain.on('toMain', (event, data) => {
    console.log(data)
    event.sender.send('fromMain', 'Hello IPC Renderer')
    // The two lines below return 'undefined' as well in the 'ipcRenderer'
    //win.webContents.send('fromMain', "Hello IPC Renderer")
    //event.reply('fromMain', 'Hello IPC Renderer')
  })

  ...
}

...
```

**vue.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      preload: 'src/preload.js',
    }
  }
}
```

**main.js** (renderer process) contains only the default project code generated upon creation.

**VueComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="vue-component">
    <v-btn @click="sendMessageToIPCMain()">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "VueComponent",
  components: {
    //
  },
  data: () => ({
    myData: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    // This works. I get 'Hello IPC Main' in the CMD console.
    sendMessageToIPCMain() {
      var message = "Hello IPC Main"
      window.ipcRenderer.send("toMain", message);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.ipcRenderer.receive('fromMain', (event, data) => {
      // this.myData = data // 'myData' is not defined error
      this.$refs.myData = data;
      console.log('myData variable: ' + this.$refs.myData) // undefined
      console.log(data) // undefined
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

The `VueComponent.vue`'s `mounted()` has been set up as described [here](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/249), though If I try to send the `data` to a variable using `this.myData = data`, I get an error saying that `myData` has not been defined - using `this.$refs.myData` works, though it's still `undefined`.

P.S. `myData` has not been defined error =/= undefined. The former is a proper error in red letters while the latter is as seen in the image above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For solving the first problem (doubling of function calls) you have to remove `window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer`. In contextIsolation mode the approach is to use contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld() only. Using both implementation definitely causes issues.

For the second problem, the callback to `receive` in ipcRenderer is called with only ...args from main (no event passed to func). see:

```
ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args)) <-- func() is called with only args
```

The only thing you should change is your function in mounted, to accept only data:

```
window.ipcRenderer.receive('fromMain', (data) => {
  console.log(data) // should log you data
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed both problems.

I was using `window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer` as well, because I didn't think it'd be possible to call `window.ipcRenderer` in the `VueComponent` without it. I thought it was just omitted in the documentation.

As for the `undefined` problem, it seems I'll have to read some more information on `arrow functions`, which is probably why I messed up there.